# How to make Gherkin style testcase as datadriven in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework, gherkin

I have a test case in Gherkin style in Robot Framework. For example:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Tests Login to website

Resource          ../keywords/resources.txt
Test Teardown     Close Browser   

*** Variables ***
${user}         demo
${userpass}     demo

*** Test Cases ***
Scenario: Login as a valid user to website
    Given Browser is opened to home page
    When I log in as ${user} with ${userpass}
    Then I can see page after sign in and verify
    And I will logout
```

Is there any way that I can run same test case for multiple sets of data?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply convert  your test case to a keyword, then use that keyword with the [Test Template](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-templates) feature. You can then create a whole set of permutations.